# How to create a rectangle with paths that has a fill and stroke and strokes doesn't overlap when alpha is < 1?

Tags: canvas, rectangles

I need to make a rectangle with paths (because I want some edges to be another color, for example or another line type dotted or so..) that don't overlap (so when I set alpha to 0.5 some edges will not be darker because of the overlap) with canvas 2d.

I've tried to do it with lineCap but it overlap in alpha...

Check what I've done, but are not good. http://jsfiddle.net/kLZfc/6/

Only with 3px works, with 1px doesn't...

```
var ctx = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('2d');
var offset;

offset = 10.5;
ctx.lineWidth = 3;
ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
ctx.lineTo(offset, offset);
ctx.lineTo(offset + 10, offset);
ctx.lineTo(offset + 10, offset + 10);
ctx.lineTo(offset, offset + 10);
ctx.lineTo(offset, offset);
ctx.stroke();



offset = 25.5;
ctx.lineWidth = 3;
ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
ctx.lineTo(offset, offset);
ctx.lineTo(offset + 10, offset);
ctx.lineTo(offset + 10, offset + 10);
ctx.lineTo(offset, offset + 10);
ctx.lineTo(offset, offset);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();



offset = 40.5;
ctx.lineWidth = 1;
ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
ctx.lineTo(offset, offset);
ctx.lineTo(offset + 10, offset);
ctx.lineTo(offset + 10, offset + 10);
ctx.lineTo(offset, offset + 10);
ctx.lineTo(offset, offset);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.stroke();



offset = 55.5;
ctx.lineWidth = 1;
ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
ctx.lineTo(offset, offset);
ctx.lineTo(offset + 10, offset);
ctx.lineTo(offset + 10, offset + 10);
ctx.lineTo(offset, offset + 10);
ctx.lineTo(offset, offset);
ctx.stroke();



offset = 70.5;
ctx.lineWidth = 1;
ctx.lineCap = "square";
ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
ctx.lineTo(offset, offset);
ctx.lineTo(offset + 10, offset);
ctx.lineTo(offset + 10, offset + 10);
ctx.lineTo(offset, offset + 10);
ctx.lineTo(offset, offset);
ctx.stroke();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is the **pixel-perfect** rectangle with inner stroke: http://jsfiddle.net/kLZfc/9/

```
var ctx = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('2d');
var offset;
ctx.strokeStyle = "black"
ctx.lineJoin = "miter";




var cSq = function(x, y, width, height, stroke){
    x = x + stroke / 2;
    y = y + stroke / 2;
    ctx.lineWidth = stroke;
    ctx.lineCap = "square";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    if(stroke === 1){
        ctx.lineTo(x + width, y);
    }else{
        ctx.lineTo(x + width - stroke, y);
    }
    ctx.moveTo(x + width - stroke, y);
    ctx.lineTo(x + width - stroke, y + height - stroke);
    ctx.lineTo(x, y + height - stroke);
    ctx.moveTo(x, y + height - stroke * 2);
    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5
    ctx.stroke()
    ctx.globalAlpha = 0.7
    ctx.fillRect(x + stroke / 2, y + stroke / 2, width - stroke*2, height - stroke*2)
}
cSq(10, 11, 10, 15, 1); cSq(15, 22, 25, 44, 5);
```